# Does azure data factory uses data catalog services?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-catalog

I am planning to use Azure Data factory for ETL process, I would like to know if Azure Data factory uses the metamodel that is captured in the Data Catalog. Please advice

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

No currently you can' t reuse Metadata stored in Azure Data Catalog in Azure Data Factory directly. You could try to reuse some of the Metadata, retrieving Data Assets via the Rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/data-catalog-data-asset), but I think that it will be faster doing the setup in Azure Data Factory. Also be aware that main focus of Data Factory is on movement and orchestration. For Big Data transformations, you will use e. g. Databricks activities, for "classic" ETL integrate SSIS.